# Issue in converting Keras H5 model tflite

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow-lite

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model( './signet.h5')
tflite_model = converter.convert()
with open('model.tflite', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(tflite_model)

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_2464/3288577076.py in <module>
      1 converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model( './signet.h5')
----> 2 tflite_model = converter.convert()
      3 # Save the model.
      4 with open('model.tflite', 'wb') as f:
      5   f.write(tflite_model)

~\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\python\lite.py in convert(self)
    795     # to None.
    796     # Once we have better support for dynamic shapes, we can remove this.
--> 797     if not isinstance(self._keras_model.call, _def_function.Function):
    798       # Pass `keep_original_batch_size=True` will ensure that we get an input
    799       # signature including the batch dimension specified by the user.

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'call'
```

I am trying to convert a h5 keras model to tflite for use in react native application but this error is shown.
I tried few of the solutions on the forum provided one of which is on [github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/40499) but didn't work.
is there a way to convert my h5 model to tflite.

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to pass the actual Keras model object to the converter's `from_keras_model method :-). See example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Create a model using high-level tf.keras.* APIs
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, input_shape=[1]),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=16, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1)
])
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mean_squared_error') # compile the model
model.fit(x=[-1, 0, 1], y=[-3, -1, 1], epochs=5) # train the model
# (to generate a SavedModel) tf.saved_model.save(model, "saved_model_keras_dir")

# Convert the model.
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
tflite_model = converter.convert()

# Save the model.
with open('model.tflite', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(tflite_model)
```

So you first need to load from the H5 file.